# Modifying FAB from inside a nested route while using BottomNavigation Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, floating-action-button

I've been having a problem while trying to personalize the FloatingActionButton, contained in a main page, from withing a nested route for a BottomNavigation. Right now what I have is this widget tree:

[image: Widget tree]

As you can see the app contains a Scaffold with a BottomNavigationBar and for each index from this BottomNavigation I have a new Navigator, from which I can navigate between nested routes. The problem is that the FAB configuration for each nested routed inside these Navigators is different, and therefore I needed to know which strategy should I use to change it's options, more specifically the icon and onPress method

**Solution:**

In the end I thought about a simple enough solution, don't know if it is the more adequate one, but it does work quite well.

Basically what I did was to create a provider in which I would have a list containing the FAB function for each route, being called accordingly with the one being displayed at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `AppScreen` a stateful widget, create an `int _currentIndex = 0` in the state and after clicking on any of the `BottomNavigationBarItem`s you can call `setState` changing the `_currentIndex`.

Then, in your `build` method you can do something like this:

```dart
Widget fabChild;
VoidCallback fabOnPressed;
if (_currentIndex == 0) {
  fabChild = ...
  fabOnPressed = ...
} else if (_currentIndex == 2) {
  // (...)
}

return Scaffold(
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: fabChild,
    onPressed: fabOnPressed,
  ),
);
```

Comment: I did exatcly that, and it solves the problem with the root screen for the navigator. But what about the other routes?